# First() uses wrong alias in order clause Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Calling `first` in Rails 4.* will add an implicit order to the SQL query.
I have problem with ordering when try to do this:

```
MyModel.select('my_model.*').from('my_model mm')
       .joins(joins_statement)
       .where(where_statement)
       .first
```

It raises exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'my_model.id' in 'order clause': 
SELECT  mm.* FROM my_model mm 
JOIN joins_statement 
WHERE where_statement 
ORDER BY `my_model`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

What am I should to do to fix this error without adding .order() in all relations with .first calling?

P.S. I have Rails 4.2.1, ruby-2.1.4.

Comment: Is your problem caused by the my_model table not having an id field?  That's what the error is saying.

Comment: The `first` implies an order. You can't get a first or last without ordering. Why you not want to add the order in the query?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, I have a tons of code with `first` method and it will take a lot of time for adding the `order` in the queries. Also, ruby code with `first` method can contained in DB and i can't control it.

Comment: @Nike0 as you noticed, `first` adds an implicit sort by primary key when not specified. You don't need to add the order to any query right now, just add the order explicitly to that query.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, I incorrectly expressed. I'll have to add the order everywhere where defined alias for the table name in relation.

Comment: The alternative is to get an invalid result from the query (given the order will be completely arbitrary based on the internal database structure)... so it depends if you care most about a query returning the correct result or saving some little bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can rather use `limit` to fetch a single record:

```
MyModel.select('my_model.*').from('my_model mm')
   .joins(joins_statement)
   .where(where_statement)
   .limit(1)
```

It is same as using `first`, only it is not ordered.

Comment: With this query you have no guarantee of which record will be returned. The order will be completely random depending on the database internal structure. I'm not saying the answer is wrong, I'm just saying the original request doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I think rails contributors had reason to add order for `.first` method. I don't think it would be right to get rid of it to solve the problem.

Comment: @Nike0 what first does is that it orders by `id` and adds `limit` 1. so if you really want to use `.first`, you can either have an `id` column in your table or you can order on some other column